# Fast-forward and rewind commands do not work on Windows 7 RC 32-bit Media Centre

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, htpc

This only happens on Media Centre (works correctly in Windows Media Player).
This only happens on Windows 7 RC (works correctly on Vista).

**Edit:**
This happens with all videos. I use [Shark007 codec pack for Windows 7](http://shark007.net/win7codecs.html).

Is anyone else experiencing this problem? Any ideas on what's causing this?

Comment: What video? all videos? What codecs do you have installed?

Comment: Do the skip buttons work as expected? Do rewind and fast-forward just do nothing or does something else happen?

Comment: Do the buttons on the remote not work or can you not rewind at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded to Windows 7 Ultimate RTM and Shark007 1.2.9 (for Windows 7).

Everything appears to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the Shark007 codec pack.  This scenario should work.  It works for me.

Comment: But then you are back to not being able to play much, right?

Comment: But you know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Windows media center will only fast forward and rewind specific formats such as mpeg and wmv. It is not a codec issue, it is a windows issue. The 30 second skip buttons should work on all formats though. Also, try unisntalli9ng the shark codec pack and install the CCCP codec pack. http://www.cccp-project.net/